# Get values from the pipe separated file

Tags: c++, string, file

I'm trying to get the 2nd and 5th column details from the pipe separated file.

5th column is getting trimmed while reading from the dummy file. i tried using the get line function also. How to get the entire 5th column in the string?

File looks like:

```
1|6705|SW|447|C/A-"WAR" FROM CAR COMPANY    |||RFD|E|0|
2|6706|CA|448|CAR TYPE OR CUST. ID, REQ     |||RFD|E|0|
3|6707|CZ|448|CAR TYPE OR CUST. ID, REQ     |||RFD|E|0|
```

The code

```
  std::string cmd = "awk -F'|'  '{ print $2, $5 }' 1.txt >> tmp.txt";
    system(cmd.c_str());// extract the two columns and write to dummy file
    ifstream read( "tmp.txt");
    std::string line;

    while (std::getline(read, line)) // Read the file line by line
    {
            std::istringstream iss(line);
            string a, b;
            if (!(iss >> a >> b)) { break; } // error
            std::cout<<"a"<<a<<"  b  "<<b<<std::endl;
    }
    read.close();
    system("rm tmp.txt");
```

The output

> key(string): 6705, value(int): C/A-"WAR"
>   key(string): 6706, value(int): CAR
>   key(string): 6707, value(int): CAR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The std::cin `>>`operator reads strings by blanks or newlines, so in your case, the value of `C/A-"WAR" FROM CAR COMPANY` will be truncated into `C/A-"WAR"`,`FROM`, `CAR` and `COMPANY`. 
You may use `getline` instead.

```
while (std::getline(read, line)) // Read the file line by line
{
        std::istringstream iss(line);
        string a, b;
        iss>>a;
        getline(iss,b);//This may work
        std::cout<<"a"<<a<<"  b  "<<b<<std::endl;
}
```